# How can i give a url to a react components using props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

Component structure's

```
const IconSkill = (props) => {
      return (
        <img
        onMouseOver={() => {
          const skillIcon = document.getElementById("skills-icon");
    
          skillIcon.classList.add("skills-icon-hover");
          setTimeout(() => {
            skillIcon.classList.remove("skills-icon-hover");
          }, 1500);
        }}
        id="skills-icon"
        className="skills-icon"
        src={require(props.srcUrl).default}
        alt={props.alt}
      />
      )
    }
```

Here you see that i am trying to give a relative URL to src img using props, and it isn't working:

```
  <IconSkill srcUrl={"../../images/skills/figma.svg"} alt="HTML Icon" />
```

Here console log error:

> react-refresh-runtime.development.js:315 Uncaught Error: Cannot find
> module '../../images/skills/figma.svg'

Comment: You should not need to `require` the srcUrl, but there are a LOT of things that are funky here.  `document.getElementById` isn't how things are done in React.  I strongly reco that you start with some basic React tuts.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to import it by giving some random name if its under "src" folder:

```
import ImageName form "../../images/skills/figma.svg";
export default function(){
 return  <IconSkill srcUrl={ImageName} alt="HTML Icon" />
}
```

If images is under public folder -> images folder then your code should be:

```
<IconSkill srcUrl={"./images/skills/figma.svg"} alt="HTML Icon" />
```

and on IconSkill Component:

```
const IconSkill = (props) => {
  return (
    <img
    onMouseOver={() => {
      const skillIcon = document.getElementById("skills-icon");

      skillIcon.classList.add("skills-icon-hover");
      setTimeout(() => {
        skillIcon.classList.remove("skills-icon-hover");
      }, 1500);
    }}
    id="skills-icon"
    className="skills-icon"
    src={props.srcUrl}
    alt={props.alt}
  />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is generally not a React code. To achieve what you want your code must look smth like this.

```
import {useState} from "react";

const IconSkill = (props) => {
const {alt, srcUrl} = props;

//you need some state to control it's hover state

const [skillsIcon, setSkillsIcon] = useState(false);


const handleHover = () => {

setSkillsIcon(true);
setTimeout(() => {
        setSkillsIcon(false);
      }, 1500);
}

return (
       <img 

onMouseOver={handleHover} 
src={srcUrl} 
className={skillsIcon ? "skills-icon-hover" : null}
id="skills-icon"
alt={alt}
/>
)
}
```